# Sphinx/Rails: How to pass an array into search conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

This (of course) works:

```
@articles = Article.search("term", :conditions => {:journal_code => "12345678"})
```

which gives me

```
Sphinx Query (4.8ms)  @journal_code 12345678
Sphinx  Found 10 results
```

However, I can't figure out how to pass an array of journal codes into the conditions.

```
@articles = Article.search("term", :conditions => {:journal_code => ["12345678", "87654321"]})
```

gives me

```
Sphinx Query (3.5ms)  @journal_code ["12345678", "87654321"]
Sphinx  Found 0 results
```

So how do I go about passing multiple journal codes into the search conditions?

**Update: this fixed it**

```
@articles = Article.search("", :conditions => {:journal_code => "12345678|87654321"})

Sphinx Query (5.9ms)  @journal_code 12345678|87654321
Sphinx  Found 20 results
```